# How to pass MPI information to ctypes in python

Tags: python, mpi, ctypes

My motivation is to pass MPI information effectively from python to C functions invoked through ctypes. I used mpi4py for MPI bindings in python. I would like to learn it through a simple example MPI code written in C and invoked through ctypes in python. I have detailed the steps and the error that I get while running below.

**C code** [*passMpi4Py.c*]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void sayhello(MPI_Comm comm)
{
  int size, rank;
  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
  printf("Hello, World! "
         "I am process %d of %d.\n",
         rank, size);
}
```

I compiled the above c code with gcc/openmpi-1.6 as follows:

*mpicc -shared -Wl,-soname,passMpi4Py -o passMpi4Py.so -fPIC passMpi4Py.c*

**Python Wrapper** [*passMpi4PyWrapper.py*]

```
import ctypes
from mpi4py import MPI
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('path-to-file/passMpi4Py/passMpi4Py.so')

testlib.sayhello(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
```

When i try to run the above code by using

*mpirun -np 4 python passMpi4PyWrapper.py*

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "passMpi4PyWrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "passMpi4PyWrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "passMpi4PyWrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    testlib.sayhello(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
    testlib.sayhello(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
    testlib.sayhello(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
  File "passMpi4PyWrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
    testlib.sayhello(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

**Update:**

Using *MPI_COMM_WORLD* instead of *comm* in the C program MPI functions helps me to remove the error. However I still would like to know if this is the best possible way to pass MPI information to a C program.

Comment: Have you tried it without the communicator?  e.g. hardcoding `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in `sayhello`?

Comment: I just tried but what is the data type i must give for MPI_COMM_WORLD in sayhello without which it gives me an error while compiling C code

Comment: No, I mean make `sayhello` a function which accepts 0 arguments.  e.g. `void sayhello(){ ...; MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);... }`

Comment: One problem here is that the type of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is of type `MPI_Comm` which could be just about anything.  It could be `typedef`ed to `int`,`long`,`long long` ... or it could even be some sort of `struct` (the standard doesn't say)`.  Likely, it is an 4 byte integer on most systems to be compatible with the fortran bindings, but that's definitely not guaranteed.

Comment: Cool. The MPI_COMM_WORLD that you suggested worked now. Thank you. But is this the best way to send MPI information from python wrapper to C code? Do you know of any books or online tutorials which deal with this in detail?

Comment: I doubt that it's the best way, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: @mgilson, although not fixed in the standard, on most implementations the C communicator handles are actually implemented as typedef'd pointers while Fortran handles are integer indexes in tables of pointers. There are the `MPI_Comm_f2c()` and `MPI_Comm_c2f()` calls to convert between Fortran integers and C handles, no matter how the C handles are actually implemented (and on LP64 systems pointers are even not the same size as Fortran `INTEGER`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a way to map Python's MPI.COMM_WORLD (which is an instance of the mpi4py's Comm class) to MPI_COMM_WORLD (which is an `int` handle).  This can be done by generating a wrapper with SWIG.  The [mpi4py tutorial](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html#wrapping-with-swig) has basically the same example as you have, but with the SWIG interface file added.

If you'd rather not use SWIG, you can perform the conversion in the C code.  If you look at the file mpi4py.i that the SWIG example is importing, you can see that conversion is done with `PyMPIComm_Get`.  `mpi4py` source comes with [an example that does not use SWIG](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/73129d2c792291a735c47bca51684ae1d524a4aa/demo/wrap-c/?at=master).